# How to check all checkboxes of parents' siblings on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to figure out what's not working here in my jQuery..

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <div class="filter-all">
        <div class="filter-select-all">Select All</div> | 
        <div class="filter-select-none">Select None</div>
    </div>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Food</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Meeting</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Music</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Outdoors</label></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MDNmx/

I've tried all kinds of different methods instead of closest and find too..

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `div` element doesn't have `checked` property!

Comment: @undefined what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/nEB9h/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
         $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

### Update:

FYI -- the HTML specification says that only `<li>` should be a direct descendant of `<ul>`, so you should change your HTML to look like:

```
<div class="filter-all">
    ...
</div>
<ul id='checkboxes'> ... </ul>
```

Then your code will look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('.filter-select-all').click(function () {
        $('#checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('.filter-select-none').click(function () {
        $('#checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

### Further update: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nEB9h/2/))

To condense the two click handlers into one, consider updating your HTML further (split `filter-select-all` into `filter-select` and `all`):

```
<div class="filter-all">
    <div class="filter-select all">Select All</div>|
    <div class="filter-select none">Select None</div>
</div>
```

Then you can use the second class for the boolean flip:

```
$(function () {
    $('.filter-select').click(function () {
        $('#checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .prop('checked', $(this).is('.all'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for the fast answer! So fast, it won't even let me accept it yet..

Answer (score 1):

1. `div` element doesn't have `checked` property, ie `this.checked === 'undefined'`
2. Your markup is invalid, `div` element should not be a direct child of `ul` element.
3. For changing properties of elements `prop` should be used instead of `attr`.

   ```
   $('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
       $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
   });
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't .find(':checkbox') only target the checkboxes though?

Comment: @Reuben it will be slower, you can use `input:checkbox` though

Comment: @Reuben Yes, it does so. But in your code `this` refers to the clicked element not checkboxes.

Comment: @undefined I think you mean `this.checked === undefined`. That's them tricky strict equality comparisons for ya `:P`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a "class" attribute on each checkbox :

   < li>< label>< input **class='check'** type="checkbox">Food< /label>< /li>
2. write javascript as follows:

> $('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
>       $('.check').each(function(k,v) {
>           v.checked = true;
>       }); });
>
> $('.filter-select-none').click(function() {
>       $('.check').each(function(k,v) {
>           v.checked = false;
>       }); });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('li').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",true);
});
$('.filter-select-none').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('li').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filter-select-all').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```