# Jquery : Set the value of checkbox

Tags: jquery

If I have 3 checkboxes in a column,onclick of any checkbox,I want to set the value of checkbox in the entire column(not row)

if checkbox in the 2nd column is checked/unchecked , I want all the other checkbox in the same column(2nd column) to be checked /unchecked.

This is the code I am trying to implement::

```
var a =$j('#table tr').length;
$j("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var ch = this.checked;
    if checked checkbox is in 2nd column , all the checkboxes in the 2nd column(td) should be checked (row length varies not static)
});
```

Comment: Could you provide code-samples and which version of jQuery you are using, please?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330765/how-to-check-all-checkboxes-of-parents-siblings-on-click-with-jquery

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your HTML. This behaviour can easily be implemented a number of ways with jQuery, so having your HTML as a starting point would let people suggest the ways most suitable for your structure.

Comment: var a =$j('#table tr').length;
$j("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
 var ch = this.checked;
 if checked checkbox is in 2nd column , all the checkboxes in the 2nd column should be checked (row length varies not static)
});

Comment: You need to provide code for this question. The term column could take on several different meanings, and posting your HTML would clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to figure out which column was clicked.

Within the click handler, `this` is the clicked checkbox, so `$(this).closest("td").index()` will give you its containing td's zero-based index within the row.

Then you can use the [`nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) (which counts from *one*, not zero) to get all of the items in that column.

You didn't show your HTML, so I've coded the following based on a very simple `<table>` structure as you can see:

```js
var table = $("table").on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
  var column = $(this).closest("td").index() + 1
  table.find("td:nth-child(" + column + ") :checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was able to acheive as you have shared :But I want to change the check box value only if the row of the checkbox conatins a particular text value.I tried the below code.But failed:

var table = $j("#table tr td:contains('Test')").on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
  var column = $j(this).closest("td").index() + 1;
  table.find("td:nth-child(" + column + ") :checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want all 3 of the checkboxes to either be checked or unchecked at the same time. This should work for you.

```
$(document).on('click', '.class1, .class2, .class3', function(){
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(checked === true) {
        $('.class1, .class2, .class3').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.class1, .class2, .class3').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Just remember to change the '.class1, .class2, .class3' to whatever classes you're using.

Comment: `this.checked` is easier to read, faster to type, and faster to execute than `$(this).prop('checked')`. You could replace the whole body of your function with one line: `$('.class1, .class2, .class3').prop('checked', this.checked);`. But anyway, this answer doesn't restrict the CB update to just the current column's checkboxes.

Comment: This is the code I am trying to implement
var a =$j('#table tr').length;
$j("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
 var ch = this.checked;
 if checked checkbox is in 2nd column , all the checkboxes in the 2nd column should be checked (row length varies not static)
});

Comment: You're welcome. (Sorry if I sounded grumpy, I just intended to be matter of fact about it, not mean.)

Comment: No worries! I completely understood and no grumpiness was detected on my end.

Answer (score 0):

As per the jQuery documentation, this can take some tweaking to get right depending on your version. https://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
<div class="column">check one:
  <input type="checkbox" value="a">
  <input type="checkbox" value="b">
  <input type="checkbox" value="c">
</div>
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']").click( function(){ 
  var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
  // console.log(checked,typeof checked);
  if( checked === true ){
    $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
  }else{
    $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
  }
} );
</script>
```

I've used `.siblings` here, but there's many other ways to do it.

**Edit: Using input from [@ottiem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157431/ottiem)**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click( function(){ 
  $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",this.checked);
} );
```

note that `this.checked` above use's javascript's `this`, not jQuery's `$(this)`